# Django, best practice to execute an action for each instance of a model

Tags: django, performance, models

here's my question.

I have a model like that

```
class ActionQueue(models.Model):
    action_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ACTION_QUEQUE_TYPE)

    def execute(self):
        if self.action_type == 'exam':
                ... do something ...
```

What's the best way to execute the function "execute" for each instance of ActionQueue ?
Currently i'm using a for..in:

```
 for action in ActionQueue.objects.all():
     action.execute()
```

Maybe there is a better way (in terms of performances) to achieve the same result..

Thank you

Comment: That's about as clean as it gets. I don't like list comprehensions for execution unless you are using the result as a list.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
actions = ActionQueue.objects.filter(action_type='exam')
```

then

```
actions.update(...)
```

or

```
action_list = list(actions)
# do something with action_list
[do_something(action) for action in action_list]
```

Comment: yes.. maybe filtering outside the execute action should have best performances... i'll do some tests.. :)